# Android canvas on layout (as opposed to view)

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas

Is it an allowed practice to put a canvas on a layout, and draw one's content there?

Comment: I don't see why not? I did that to do a custom electronic signature activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a layout, I assume it's because it contains child views? You can override `dispatchDraw` to do some customization before or after you ask the children to draw themselves.

I have done that to add a bookshelf background to my `GridView`, for instance:
http://chiuki.github.io/fluid-android-layouts/#31

Another example is to rotate the canvas before drawing:
http://chiuki.github.io/android-custom-components/#46